# blob data not set as bitmap on imageview android

Tags: android, sqlite, bitmap, imageview, blob

i have insert blob data in to sqlite and retrive from sqlite that time blob data not set as bitmap on imageview. give msg to fail to load. so please help me for my code. following are my code.

```
            bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
             .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


            ByteArrayOutputStream stream= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte imginbyte[]=stream.toByteArray();
            byte temp[]=imginbyte;

            myDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO tableimage VALUES('"+temp+"');");
            Cursor c= myDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tableimage", null);
            c.moveToLast();
            byte asd[]= c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("imgpath"));
            byte img[]=null;

          //  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(asd, 0, asd.length);
            ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
            ImageView iv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img3);

            iv.setImageBitmap( BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(asd, 0, asd.length));
            iv1.setImageBitmap( BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(asd, 0, asd.length));
```

Comment: is it store success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without blob store image and retrive. with string database see below code

```
bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
             .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
            String encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

            byte[] bytarray = Base64.decode(encodedImageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bmimage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytarray, 0,
                    bytarray.length);

            myDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO imgtbl VALUES('"+encodedImageString+"');");
            Cursor c= myDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM imgtbl", null);

           c.moveToFirst();
           String img=c.getString(0);
           byte[] byarray = Base64.decode(img, Base64.DEFAULT);
           Bitmap bmimg = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byarray, 0,
                   byarray.length);

            ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
            ImageView iv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img3);

            iv.setImageBitmap(bmimg);
            iv1.setImageBitmap(bmimg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ByteArrayInputStream imageStreamFront = new ByteArrayInputStream(asd);

Bitmap bitFrontImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStreamFront);

if(bitFrontImage!=null)
{
   iv.setImageBitmap(bitFrontImage, 40);
}
```

Comment: can you explain for bitFrontImage

Comment: thnk you fro that. but i get same problem toast to print fail to load.\

Comment: now you must check weather you are storing it correctly or not

Comment: myDb = openOrCreateDatabase("image",Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
 
   myDb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableimage1(image blob);");myDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO tableimage VALUES('"+temp+"');");
             Cursor c= myDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tableimage", null);